# Magento 1.9 - MYGENTO_ logs flood server

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I got e-mails from my host that the server was almost full, which was alarming because this particular shop is hosted on a huge server and only takes about 20% of the diskspace.

So I took to SSH to find out what folders were so huge, and I found that there are hundreds of `MYGENTO_*.log` files in a lot of different folders. This has never happened before, but must be going on for quite some time now because it takes some time before the disk is almost full.

I found and removed them all via SSH, but as soon as I delete them, they pop up again. So there must be some 'active logging' going on.

So I searched the filesystem for the filename and came up with two mentions in one file: `/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php` creates these files (around line 486);

```
 /**
 * Prepares and executes an SQL statement with bound data.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $sql  The SQL statement with placeholders.
 *                      May be a string or Zend_Db_Select.
 * @param  mixed  $bind An array of data to bind to the placeholders.
 * @return Zend_Db_Statement_Interface
 */

private static $_numcall = 0;
public function query($sql, $bind = array())
{

[...]

    file_put_contents('MYGENTO_.log', json_encode(array(
        'timestamp' => $ta,
        '_numcall' => self::$_numcall,
    )) . "\n\r", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    [...]

    if($dt > 1) {
        file_put_contents('MYGENTO_.log', json_encode(array(
            'DELTA' => $dt,
            'sql' => $sql,
        )) . "\n\r", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

My first guess would be to just comment out these actions, but I'm hesitant because this is apparently in the core, and I've never had problems with it before. So my question is, why now all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, already found it - I think. I couldn't find anything on "mygento logs" and upon further investigation I saw that the Abstract.php file was edited by someone else, and an earlier backup of the file had no mention of "mygento" whatsoever.

So it's probably a third party developer or someone from the hosting company who once added it for debugging purposes, and forgot to remove it. I set back the previous version of the file, the logging stops, everybody happy.